# Renaming of administrator directory

Tags: security

Can be **administrator** directory effectively renamed (for example by simple change in Joomla! core code) for example to **admTZ34**? The main reason is to obfuscate standard pattern where **www.example.com/administrator** could be used to check presence of Joomla! installation (in older releases also Joomla! version etc.)

Comment: Before Joomla SE was set up I asked this same question here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034980/change-joomla-administrator-url

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not really recommended or very simple to do. The admin path gets hardcoded in a lot of extensions with calls to things like JTables which means changing the directory name could have a lot of consequences.

That said if you want to prevent direct access try with one of this solutions:

**A)** Password protect **/administrator** with a **.htaccess** password protection. 
    This uses HTTP authentication to prevent anyone from getting to the admin directory.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html

**B)** Require a keyword in the URL with an extension like:

- [AdminExile](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/adminexile)
- [JSecure](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/jsecure-lite)
- [KSecure](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/ksecure)
- [Admin Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/ksecure)

  Admin tools is capable of doing both options for you.

  With one of this extensions the admin url will be: 
  yoursite.com/administrator/**?mySpecialPhrase**

Comment: Quick question regarding your first point. Will protecting it using a .htaccess file prevent files being moved the necessary directories within the administrator folder upon installation of extensions?

Comment: I don't believe so because .htpasswd will only check for http access. When copying files around via the installer I think all that happens at the server level so I don't think this will matter. That said, I have seen issues with things like javascript being stored in /administrator and being called via HTTP on the front end and asking users to login. So this isn't always a workable solution.

Comment: @ChadWindnagle +1 from my side in your answer and your comments.  Backend Protection through htaccess is a good solution but few extension fetch site's images and javascript  from site's backend, In-that case htaccess restrict to access these images and javascripts.

Comment: Continue @ChadWindnagle answer 
 3) Use two factor authentication http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/24822

Comment: Nice suggestion on 2 factor. That said I think it's in Joomla 3.2+ so an extension shouldn't be necessary if running latest version of Joomla.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really change it as it would prevent extensions from installing properly. You can however use Admin Exile which allows you to add a value, key or both to the administrator URL. In addition to this, if the standard admin URL is typed it, it will redirect the user to a site of your choice.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/15711

Hope this helps

Comment: So if I understand, the main problem is plugins, right? Can it be said that Joomla! installation without extensions can withstand renaming of administrator directory relatively safely?

Comment: Extensions in general, not just plugins. There are also other reasons why you should not change the name of the folder. One reason @Chad explains regarding JTables

Comment: In addition to that, the whole thought process of renaming /administrator/ in general as a practice is not a good one. It's not "real" security. The author of Akeeba backup and a Joomla security expert wrote about a similar type of move regarding configuration.php [http://www.dionysopoulos.me/keep-your-files-where-i-can-see-them/] I'd recommend reading that to understand why this type of change is frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

If your only concern is bad-bots identifying your website as joomla website then you need to do a lot more to hide this truth.

A lot of technique exist to identify your website as joomla and its version.
This [.htaccess](http://docs.joomla.org/Htaccess_examples_%28security%29) file helps in these attacks.